# No cookie matching signin id found

Tags: owin, identityserver3, katana

I have implemented identityserver3 and it work well but sometime , i get error while redirecting to IDS(for login). Log says **No matching Cookie signin Id** . 
I can see initial login cookie is not being sent to identityserver from our application in some cases.

I did some googling and it seems like existing issue with Katana and suggestion was too use app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver() but even after that it doesn't seems to be working.

Another strange this is that .. problem appear only one time per browser session (that too 1st time) and doesn't appear after that or if i get app-pool reset it doesn't happen for sometime.

Is there something else i can try? Looking forward for any direction. 
Thanks in advance.

**Identity Log**

04/19/2017 07:52:53 -07:00 [Information] ()
Posting to https://applicationURl/
04/19/2017 07:52:53 -07:00 [Information] ()
Login page submitted
04/19/2017 07:52:53 -07:00 [Information] ()
No cookie matching signin id found
04/19/2017 07:52:53 -07:00 [Information] ()
Start discovery request
04/19/2017 07:52:53 -07:00 [Information] ()
Start key discovery request
04/19/2017 07:52:53 -07:00 [Information] ()
CSP Report endpoint requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue was reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1299).

Maybe this blog post helps: [Catching the System.Web/Owin Cookie Monster](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/catching-the-system-webowin-cookie-monster/).

It suggests to workaround this issue by adding `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` to the Owin pipeline using the [Kentor.OwinCookieSaver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.OwinCookieSaver) NuGet package.